# Как заменить картинку скриптом?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Всем привет.

Есть `ui image` и нужно, чтобы при событии заменялась картинка на другую.
Как можно заменить картинку скриптом?

Это то, что я смог сделать, но это не хочет работать:

```
img1.GetComponent().sprite = Resources.Load("2.png");
```

и так

```
img1.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("2.png");
```

Comment: Что такое img1?(какой тип)

Comment: Это название UI>Image в convas'e

Comment: У вас синтаксис JS, а не C#

Comment: ahaha разве. видео уроке так было, ну как так, там они текст меняли. я хочу так же но картинку поменять).
---
 Header.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Text header";

Comment: @ValeraKvip вот вы изменили код, а ведь это два разных кода... от ТС был на JS, а вот этот на C# и мог стать вполне рабочим примером (если исключить нюансы).... так что кмк, не надо было это менять

Comment: @Mr.Husky в итоге как вы писали код? так `img1.GetComponent().sprite = Resources.Load("2.png");` или так `img1.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("2.png");` ?

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, не менял, там было два каких то тега типа <code> и еще какой то, я заменил их на теги форума . Сам удивился что код изменился, думал так и надо.

Comment: Я по логике использовал img1.GetComponent<Image>().Image = "2" но на это он ругался. далее полез в гугл и оттуда брал решение и вставлял в свой. вот один из них вы видите в топе)

Comment: @Mr.Husky кстати, какой `TextureType` у картинки и `SpriteMode`?

Comment: Sprite (2D and UI) и single

Answer (score 4):

Предположу, что так:

```
img1.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("2");
```

или так:

```
img1.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = Resources.Load("2") as Sprite;
```

При загрузке с ресурсов не нужно указывать расширение  файлов. Загрузка ориентируется по имени. Плюс, емнип, у UI кнопок компонент не `SpriteRenderer`, а `Image`

Если не сработает `.sprite`, попробуй через `overrideSprite`, т.е.

```
img1.GetComponent<Image>().overrideSprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("2");
```

Кстати, если `img1` это ссылка на объект UI типа `Image`, то можно писать сразу

```
img1.sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("2");
```

безо всяких `GetComponent<Image>()`

---

Напомню, что при таком подходе в настройках текстуры должен быть выставлен `TextureType` - Sprite (2D and UI), `SpriteMode` - Single.

Если у картинки тип `Texture`, то нужно будет в начале загружать как текстуру, а потом применять `Sprite.Create` для создания спрайта.

Comment: Какие библиотеки нужно подключить для overridesprite/sprite.   пишет "...не удалось найти метод расширения <spirte> ...."

Comment: @Mr.Husky да никакие ... только `using UnityEngine.UI;` ...... `Sprite` надо с заглавной буквы писать

Comment: В начале писать public Transform img1; или public GameObject img1;?
При transform выходит вот это http://image.prntscr.com/image/188fb5e4e9404001a0b2ddc4394389b9.png 
При public http://image.prntscr.com/image/2599ba0648d340c0a6c1294cc4ea521b.png

Comment: @Mr.Husky зачем `Transform img1;` ? там будут какие-либо манипуляции с перемещением? если нет, то можно так: `Image img1;` ........... если же у вас он `Transform`, то тогда конечно же надо писать `img1.GetComponent<Image>().sprite`..........на счет `Sprite` - с большой буквы я сказал писать потому, что думал, что вы её с маленькой пишете в угловых скобках у конструкции  Resources.Load)) а так конечно с маленькой............ то есть в вашем случае будет так `img1.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("2");` ......... и не копируйте слепо)) а то мои `arrows2` у вас нет ;-)

Comment: Все равно ругается на "Sprite" пишу ли с большой или меленькой буквой Sprite

Comment: @Mr.Husky потому что что-то делаешь не так))  .... еще раз.... если у тебя `Transform img1;` то надо писать `img1.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("2");`.  Если у тебя `Image img1;` то можно писать и так `img1.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("2");` и так `img1.sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("2");`

Comment: Хоть через Transform img1 или же image img1. Все равно конфликтует c sprite:(

Comment: @Mr.Husky я не верю))) кинь полный код

Comment: Если поможет http://image.prntscr.com/image/99b72180664e46ba9af2c080a627c9ce.png Это при image img1;

Comment: @Mr.Husky не не не. именно **полный** код... весь класс...и не картинкой

Comment: скинул код. что мы писали в самом конце

Comment: @Mr.Husky надо `img1.sprite` ...... с маленькой........ С большой надо у Resources.Load<Sprite> писать

Comment: Все так же в доступном в списке его тоже нет http://image.prntscr.com/image/32500c9b096b4fa9a014a8c071f8b35c.png

Comment: Посмотрите полный код чуть ниже. (если не видели)

Comment: @Mr.Husky магия.. попробуй удалить строку... сохрани... выйди из юнити и всех программ, перезагрузи комп... и с нового компа попробуй снова строку написать.. может глюк

Comment: @Mr.Husky, код, не являющийся ответом, следует размещать в вопросе.

Comment: Так же. что не так

Comment: @Mr.Husky честно не знаю. твой код у меня работает (с маленькой буквой `S`)..... то есть что-то у тебя либо с редактором либо с VS. Может в кэше где-то что-то..... на данный момент бОльшего сказать нечего

Comment: если через `Public Sprite img1` и `img1 = Resources.Load<Sprite>("2");`
то тогда не ругается, но что то не заменяет картинку) 

как тут http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27761021/4-6-new-ui-how-to-change-button-image

Comment: @Mr.Husky увы, но рабочий вариант описан в ответе. Как я уже писал - даже ВАШ код у меня работает. Больше, к сожалению, я ничем не могу помочь.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Я исправил положение.теперь на sprite не ругается. только теперь картинка не загружается. а с картинками вроде все норм Sprite 2D and UI и Single mode